# Execute hive query on spark - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Im trying to get Hive on Spark working properly but it seems like it is not loading the hive-exec-2.0.1.jar. 
I can get Hive on mr to work perfectly fine. 
Im using Hive 2.0.1 and Spark 1.6.1. Followed the Hive on Spark tutorial. 
I set all the necessary properties on hive-site.xml, linked the spark assembly jar into the hive lib folder, I already have all the environment variables set (SPARK_HOME, etc). 
I started the Spark master and worker. Also started the hiveserver2 with DEBUG level. Tried to run a simple query "select count(*)..." and as far as I see in the hive logs, its executing the spark-submit command with all the nesscary arguments including the hive-exec-2.0.1.jar file but still I see that during the execution I get:

---

```
16/07/29 18:14:51 [RPC-Handler-3]: WARN rpc.RpcDispatcher: Received error message:io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:358)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:230)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.KryoMessageCodec.decode(KryoMessageCodec.java:97)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec$1.decode(ByteToMessageCodec.java:42)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.spark.client.Job
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 more
.
16/07/29 18:14:51 [RPC-Handler-3]: WARN client.SparkClientImpl: Client RPC channel closed unexpectedly.
```

---

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?
I tried everything: set the spark.jars property, link the hive-exec-2.0.1.jar, set the spark.executor..property, etc.

It seems like it should work without any problems, but for some reason I cant get it to work...

Anything else?

Comment: Do you have copy of `hive-site.xml` file in `$SPARK_HOME/conf` dir?

Comment: yes and the HiveContext initiates successfully

Comment: Looks like spark 1.6.1 is compatible with hive 1.2.1 - you should try downgrading hive to 1.2.1 version - http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: tried it as well - same problem. seems like the even though the spark-submit adding the hive-exec file, it still not being added into the executor classpath...any other idea?

Comment: solved it by adding the property: spark.driver.extraClassPath and point to:  hive-exec-1.2.1.jar

Comment: Great...adding that in classpath.txt should have work too.

Answer (score 1):

These are the changes I had to make along with copying `hive-site.xml` to `$SPARK_HOME/conf` dir when I set up spark on cloudera VM:

Add these lines in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/classpath.txt` file:

```
/home/cloudera/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-1.2.1-yarn-shuffle.jar
/usr/jars/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar
```

Add this property in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf` file (same assembly jar that you have copied to hive lib - I did not need to copy assembly jar to hive lib.):

```
spark.yarn.jar=local:/home/cloudera/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

Also check jars version of hive set in classpath.txt files are the same version of yours, and location(absolute path) is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding the property: spark.driver.extraClassPath and point to: hive-exec-1.2.1.jar

Comment: right after that I had another issue: executing the query caused a java.lang.AbstractMethodError exception to be thrown. Finally the compatible versions are: Spark-1.6.2 with Hive-2.0.1 or Spark 1.4.1 with Hive-1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The version of Spark compatible with old newer version of Hive 1.2 onwards is Spark 1.3.1. That is the only one I have managed to make it work and it is production ready. This is not built on any vendor's version. I presented this in Hortonworks talk. Details from [here](https://talebzadehmich.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/hive_on_spark_only.pdf)

HTH,

Mich

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.